# 11 empty files appeared in my home folder

Tags: files, home-directory

11 files appeared in my home folder today. They are all empty and have 1 letter names (b, f, g, h, k, l, m, n, p, x, and y). They all claim to have been created on December 5th, but if that were really the case, I would probably would have noticed earlier than today (December 31st).

I don't know where these files came from. It's possible I created them at some point and just forgot. If not, I want to know where they came from.

Comment: Have you checked you shell history (e.g. `history | grep touch`)?

Comment: `$ history|grep touch`

`2000  history|grep touch`